# ¿Cómo saber cuándo es la última iteración de mi ciclo for?

Tags: javascript, loops, ciclos

Me gustaría saber en qué momento mi ciclo for hará su última iteración. Con esto quiero decir que solo quiero que haga una acción, pero que sea hasta el final del ciclo.

Un ejemplo seria el siguiente:

```
for (var i=0; i<accordeon; i++) {
  if (UltimaIteracion) {
    // Instrucciones de la última iteración
  }
}
```

Me interesa solo la iteración final, esto es, si hay 5 iteraciones solo la número 5 activara el `if`. La variable `accordeon` es de tipo entero y proviene de la BD, por ende no siempre tiene el mismo valor.

Comment: Si un loop for itera desde 0 hasta N - 1, donde N es el número de iteraciones, entonces, es tan simple como `i === accordeon - 1`.

Comment: ¿No sería más sencillo que las instrucciones de la última interación se coloquen fuera del bloque del for?

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo con @Rubén, en muchos lenguajes se puede utilizar el bucle para que el iterador nos deje en la última posición. Luego, después del `for`, se puede actuar sobre ese último elemento. De todos modos, si lo que pretendes es hacer una acción sobre un solo elemento, utilizar un bucle no parece la solución más óptima.

Comment: Ni la más óptima ni la más lógica. No tiene sentido usar un bucle si solo se va a usar un único elemento, imagina si fuese un array de objetos pesados, las op/s caerían en picada y gastarías memoria en vano. Por lo que, supongo que el OP *hace otras operaciones* dentro del loop. Aún así, como dice @Rubén, es código innecesario. Si `for` y `Array#forEach` son funciones/estructuras síncronas, fácilmente podrías tener la lógica para "la última iteración" fuera del bucle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quedaria algo asi

```js
for (var i=0;i<accordeon;i++)   {
     if (i == (accordeon-1) ) {

        //  Instrucciones de la ultima iteracion //
     
     }

}
```

Comment: Debe notarse que esta solución solo se puede garantizar válida si dentro de las instrucciones del `for` no se modifican los valores de `i` ni de `accordeon`

Comment: @Sam el problema es que si modificas `i` o `accordeon` dentro del ciclo `for`, violarias varios principios de desarrollo. Te recomiendo que leas sobre inmutabilidad y programacion funcional.

Answer (score 7):

Si bien otras respuestas responden el ejemplo particular de tu pregunta, para responder la duda subyacente (*¿Cómo saber cuándo es la última iteración de mi ciclo for?*) vale la pena recordar el funcionamiento del bucle `for`.

### Estructura del bucle `for`

Su forma general en JS (y en muchos otros lenguajes) es la siguiente:

```
for(/*expresión inicial*/; /*condición*/; /*expresión final*/)
{
  /*sentencias a ejecutar*/
}
```

- **Expresión inicial**

> Una expresión o declaración de variable, la cual típicamente se utiliza como variable `contador`.

- **Condición**

> Una expresión para ser evaluada antes de cada iteración del bucle. Si esta expresión se evalúa como verdadera, se ejecutan las `sentencias a ejecutar`. Si la expresión se evalúa como falsa, la ejecución salta a la primera expresión que sigue al bucle `for`.

- **Expresión final**

> Una expresión para ser evaluada al final de cada iteración del bucle. Esto ocurre antes de la siguiente evaluación de la `condición`. Generalmente se usa para actualizar o incrementar la variable `contador`.

- **Sentencias a ejecutar**

> Un conjunto de sentencias que se ejecutan sucesivamente, mientras la `condición` se evalúe como verdadera.

<sup>(Definiciones adaptadas de la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for))</sup>

### Funcionamiento del bucle `for`

Su funcionamiento es el siguiente:

1. Se ejecuta la `expresión inicial`
2. Se evalúa la `condición`.
3. Ocurre uno de los siguientes casos:
   3.1 Si la `condición` se evaluó verdadera, vamos al **paso 4**
   3.2 Si la `condición` se evaluó falsa, vamos al **paso 7**
4. Se ejecutan las `sentencias a ejecutar`
5. Se ejecuta la `expresión final`
6. Volvemos al **paso 2**.
7. Salimos del bucle `for`

Gráficamente, equivale a este flujo: [**ver imagen**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#/media/File:For-loop-diagram.png).

> **Nota**: Para quienes estén familiarizados con el bucle `while`, mas no con `for`, vale la pena notar que el siguiente código equivale al `for` recién expuesto.

```
/*expresión inicial*/
while(/*condición*/)
{
  /*sentencias a ejecutar*/

  /*expresión final*/
}
```

### Determinando la última iteración del bucle `for`

> **La mala noticia**: no siempre es posible determinar dentro de las `sentencias a ejecutar` si es que estás en la última iteración del `for`.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente caso, en la `expresión final` del bloque asignamos un número entero al azar entre 1 y 10 a la variable `i`.

```
for(var i=0; i<=5; i=Math.floor(Math.random()*1)-10){
  // No hay manera de saber si estamos en la última iteración, pues
  // después de esta sección se ejecutará la `expresión final` y recién
  // después se evaluará la `condición` para determinar si volvemos a entrar acá.
}
```

Ahora bien, eso está lejos de ser lo habitual :)

> **La buena noticia**: Dentro de cada iteración, si es que puedes determinar el valor que tendrá la `condición` después de ejecutar primero las `sentencias a ejecutar` y luego la `expresión final` (en ese orden), entonces puedes saber si estás (o no) en la última iteración

**Caso típico**

El uso más típico de `for`, que es también el que usas en tu ejemplo, es el siguiente:

- **Expresión inicial**: Declara una variable `i` entera con un valor inicial
  <sup>(p. ej. `var i=0` o `var i=valorInicial`)</sup>
- **Condición**: Evalúa que la variable sea menor a un valor o a otra variable
  <sup>(p. ej. `i<42` o `i<accordeon`)</sup>
- **Expresión final**: Aumenta en uno el valor de la variable
  <sup>(p. ej. `i++` o `i=i+1`)</sup>
- **Sentencias a ejecutar**: Usan la variable `i`, pero sin modificarla.
  <sup>(p. ej. `console.log("Esta es la iteración"+i);` o `arreglo[i] = 3*i;`)</sup>

Para este caso típico, sabemos que una vez ejecutadas las `sentencias a ejecutar`, la variable `i` aumentará su valor en 1. Esto hace que las siguientes formas sean maneras válidas de verificar si estamos en la última iteración:

```
for(var i=0; i<42; i++){
  // Si es que (i+1) no es menor a 42
  if(!( (i+1)<42 )){
    console.log("Esta es la última iteración");
  }      
}
```

Lo equivale a:

```
for(var i=0; i<42; i++){
  // Si es que i es igual 42-1
  if(i == 41){
    console.log("Esta es la última iteración");
  }      
}
```

> **Nota**: La afirmación *"estamos en la última iteración del* `for`*"* equivale a decir *"la próxima vez que se evalúe la* `condición`*, esta será falsa"*.

### Yendo a tu ejemplo

```
for (var i=0; i<accordeon; i++) {
  if (/*UltimaIteracion*/) {
    // Instrucciones de la ultima iteración
  }
}
```

Se traduce a a:

```
for (var i=0; i<accordeon; i++) {
  if (! ((i+1)<accordeon) ) {
    // Instrucciones de la ultima iteración
  }
}
```

Lo que equivale a

```
for (var i=0; i<accordeon; i++) {
  if (i == accordeon-1) {
    // Instrucciones de la ultima iteración
  }
}
```

> Nota final: Por todo lo anterior, debes notar que **esto funcionará siempre y cuando no modifiques el valor de** `i` **ni el de** `accordeon` **dentro de las** `sentencias a ejecutar` **de tu** `for`. En caso contrario, la verificación podría ser imposible, o bien la expresión `UltimaIteracion` para el `if` podría verse alterada.

Comment: Bien currado, Sam. Esto parece más un tutorial xD

Answer (score 0):

accordeon es un array?  o que tipo de variable es.  si es un array seria asi:

```
if (i === (accordeon.length-1)){
    //sentencias en la ultima iteracion
}
```

si no es un array seria asi :

```
if (i === (accordeon-1)){
    //sentencias en la ultima iteracion
}
```

Comment: accordeon es una variable de tipo entero, pero no es un arreglo, solo almacenaria un valor.

Answer (score 0):

Como te han indicado en otras respuestas es tan sencillo como hacer

```
if ( i == (accordeon - 1)) {
// Instrucciones de la última iteración
}
```

Lo puedes hacer con una variable de tipo boolean como has puesto en tu ejemplo, pero siempre tendrás que hacer un if para ir comparando el valor de i con tu límite, en este caso accordeon.

```
for (var i=0; i < accordeon ; i++){

if(i==(accordeon-1)) UltimaIteracion=true

if (UltimaIteracion) { // Instrucciones de la última iteración } }
```

Aunque me parece más simple y correcta la primera opción.

Answer (score -1):

Es bastante simple, solo debes comparar que *i* (el contador para el ciclo) sea igual a la cantidad de *items* dentro del `arreglo`

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if (i == arr.length - 1){
        console.log('Esta es la última iteración')
        console.log(arr[i]) 
     }
}
```